# Calculating conjugate momenta for a spin-2 field

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, tensor-calculus, canonical-conjugation

Consider a symmetric spin-2 field $h_{\mu \nu}$. I have the following Lagrangian for this field:

$$\mathcal{L} = - \frac{1}{4}\left(\partial_{\lambda}h_{\mu \nu} \text{ } \partial_{\phi}h_{\alpha \beta} \text{ } \eta^{\phi \lambda} \text{ } \eta^{\alpha \mu} \text{ } \eta^{\beta \nu}\right)$$

Since the field is symmetric, then for off-diagonal components I expect that there will be two contributions. That is:

$$\pi^{12} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial\left(\partial_0h_{12}\right)}$$

but

$$\pi^{11} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial\left(\partial_0h_{11}\right)} \ \ .$$

I want to obtain a general expression for the conjugate momenta which reproduces the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ wherever necessary. So far, I have tried the following:

$$\pi^{\rho \sigma} =  \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial\left(\partial_0h_{\rho \sigma}\right)} = \\-\frac{1}{4}\left[\partial_{\lambda}h_{\mu \nu} \text{ } \eta^{\lambda \phi} \eta^{\alpha \mu}\eta^{\beta \nu}\delta^0_{\phi}\left(\delta^{\rho}_{\alpha}\delta^{\sigma}_{\beta} + \delta^{\sigma}_{\alpha}\delta^{\rho}_{\beta}\right) + \partial_{\phi}h_{\alpha \beta} \text{ } \eta^{\lambda \phi} \eta^{\alpha \mu}\eta^{\beta \nu}\delta^0_{\lambda}\left( \delta^{\rho}_{\mu}\delta^{\sigma}_{\nu} + \delta^{\sigma}_{\mu}\delta^{\rho}_{\nu} \right) \right]$$
$$\implies \pi^{\rho \sigma} = -\frac{1}{4}\left(-4 \partial_0h^{\rho \sigma}\right)$$

But this is obviously incorrect. I would like to know where I am making a mistake, and how I can get a general expression for the conjugate momenta.

Comment: What about making use of the levi-civita antisymmetric tensor?

Comment: (a) Just to be clear, that isn't the right Lagrangian for a massless spin-2 field, although as a mathematical device for testing the calculation of conjugate momenta it is fine. (b) Since $h_{\mu\nu}$ is symmetric you should use the symmetrized derivative 
$$
\pi^{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_0 h_{\mu\nu})} + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_0 h_{\nu\mu})}\right)
$$
This should work for any $\mu, \nu$.

Comment: @Andrew do you mean the second (similar) term involving $h^{\lambda}_{\lambda}$ and the gauge condition on the field $h_{\mu \nu}$? I have excluded that term only for the purposes of putting up this question, since $h^{\lambda}_{\lambda}$ can be treated independently of $h_{\mu \nu}$.

Comment: The correct action is the Fierz-Pauli action. See Eq. 2.32 of the review by de Rham (https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4173), with the coefficients in Eq. 2.35. That review also explains why other choices of coefficients lead to theoretical problems if you try to treat it as a theory of a massless spin-2 field. But, if you're only interested in how to manipulate Lagrangians to compute a conjugate momentum, it's fine as an example.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the Fierz-Pauli action, in the de Donder gauge. I also used the symmetrized derivative, and I am getting the desired result if I use $h^{\mu \nu}\delta^{12}_{\mu \nu} = h^{12}\delta^{12}_{12} + h^{21}\delta^{12}_{21.} $ Is this true? Where can I read more about such higher rank Kronecker delta tensors?